# How to get the memory address of all operands on an expression

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-3.0, llvm-ir

I have some expression as `a=b+c-d*e`, and with the help of LLVM pass I want to make a string like this

"[Hexadecimal address of 'b'] [opcode of +] [Hexadecimal address of 'c'] [opcode of -] [Hexadecimal address of 'd'] [opcode of *] [Hexadecimal address of 'e']".

Than how can I do it .

Comment: Since you want addresses, such a string cannot be fully constructed during compilation... are you looking to inject `printf` calls into your code or something like that? Also, keep in mind you need to ensure that all of the variables will actually reside in memory.

Comment: Actually I want to pass this string as an argument to a function (let say it will just print it in on stdout), and this function will be called before every store instruction. Do you know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, keep in mind that variables do not necessarily reside in memory; they can be stored in registers or elided altogether. In the context of LLVM IR, it means either the value will be used directly from another value (without store or load).

Assuming all the variables involved do need to be loaded from memory, the most straightforward way I can think of for doing this is locating the `store`, then doing a post-order DFS backwards through the operands, recording the opcodes, and stopping when you identify a load. For your provided snippet, it should give you b's load, then plus opcode, then c's load, then minus opcode, etc.

Now that you have such a sequence, I'd say the simplest way to generate a string from it is to insert a call to C's `sprintf` with a dynamically-built format string, passing it the pointers that you found (that were `load`ed from).

I see two issues with the above, though:

1. There's some inherent ambiguity here - just visiting them this way cannot distinguish, for example, `(b+c-d)*e` from `b+(c-d)*e`. So I think it would make sense to also record "(" and ")" whenever you enter an arithmetic instruction and leave it, respectively.
2. This approach does not actually check that all the operations are part of the same expression. So if you have `tmp = b+c; a = tmp-d*e;`, and `tmp` is optimized away, then it will look the same in the IR. The only way I can think of for enforcing that is compiling with debug symbols and digging into those to identify distinct expressions - though I don't really know if that's possible - or actually modify Clang to record expression boundaries :\

Pseudo-code for this approach (with simplistic sequence-handling operations):

```
functionPass:
  for each instruction:
    if instruction is store:
      processExpression(store)

processExpression(store):
  sequence <- initialize
  visit(sequence, store.value)
  generateSprintfCallFromSequence(sequence)

visit(sequence, value):
  if value is load:
    sequence.add(load.pointer)
  else if value is binaryop:
    // sequence.add(openingParen)
    visit(sequence, binaryop.operand(0))
    sequence.add(binaryop.opcode)
    visit(sequence, binaryop.operand(1))
    // sequence.add(closingParen);
```

Comment: can "use-def" be of any use in this scenario?

Comment: @AbhinashJain sure, but you need to invoke it recursively - it only gives you the immediate operands, while you want the operands' operands as well, and so on (until the `load`s).

Comment: but at which load will I stop (most recent or oldest)? I mean there will be different number of operands on different expression, due to which there will be different number of load operations as well. So how to use "use-def" efficiently for this purpose?

Comment: @AbhinashJain what I meant what to do a DFS until you encounter a `load` - in other words, when you see a `load`, add the pointer to your sequence, and do *not* continue to visit the `load`'s operands. The number of `load`s should be identical to the number of variables in the expression (with the caveats mentioned in my answer above).

Comment: Yes I got your DFS concept, but what am still not sure about is that how will I be knowing the number of variables in the expression?

Comment: Let me summarise the whole thing and tell me where am going wrong. I count the number of loads operations occuring in between two Store opeartion, and when I encounter 2nd Store operation I traceback to Load that number of times to get all the addresses.

Comment: @AbhinashJain "between two store operations" - no, just look at a single store operation, and work backward from there on the store's value operand and its operands and their operands and so on. There should only be one store per expression. I suggest taking a look at the generated IR from compiling that expression, if you haven't yet, to better understand how it is structured. Also, if I wasn't clear, I'm only referring to walking backwards on the operand-usage chain; just walking serially on instructions is meaningless.

Comment: "operand-usage chain" will it be take care by use-def ? i.e. using use-def recursively for n(equal to load) number of times.

Comment: @AbhinashJain added pseudo-code to my answer to clarify my proposed approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot and +1 for your patience.